# How do I get the latest timestamp for each month in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, momentjs

I have an array with a bunch of objects and some key/value pairs + timestamp (moment.js formatted timestamp) in it.
I have many timestamps for 12 months in total and need to get the last timestamp for each month and drop the other objects.

Actually I don't even know how to start off. 
I used _.sortBy to order the array by date already but don't know how to move on.

```
array1 = [
{name:name1,timestamp:2018-09-15T07:00:00.0},
{name:name2,timestamp:2018-09-15T12:00:00.0},
{name:name3,timestamp:2018-09-28T05:00:00.0},
{name:name4,timestamp:2018-09-30T01:00:00.0},
{name:name5,timestamp:2018-10-02T10:00:00.0},
{name:name6,timestamp:2018-10-02T11:00:00.0},
{name:name7,timestamp:2018-10-15T07:00:00.0},
{name:name8,timestamp:2018-12-05T08:00:00.0},
{name:name9,timestamp:2018-12-05T09:00:00.0},
{name:name10,timestamp:2018-12-05T10:00:00.0}
]
```

expected result is

```
array1 = [
{name:name4,timestamp:2018-09-30T01:00:00.0},
{name:name7,timestamp:2018-10-15T07:00:00.0},
{name:name10,timestamp:2018-12-05T10:00:00.0}
]
```

Comment: Do you want the last timestamp based on the order they are presented in the array, or based on the entry having the latest timestamp for that month? For example: if the last two entries in your array switched timestamp values, would you still expect `name10` in your result set, or would you expect `name9`? If all you care about is "last based on order" @Taki answer is a good solution. If you expect the values to be randomized in your array and you want "the last entry of each month based on timestamp" it will not work.

Comment: @dusthaines I want the last entry based on the timestamp. Taki's answer works good but I'm using .map to create my array how I need it, then reduce and then push again to push the entries in a new array to get rid of the month object itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reduce` the array to an object having months as keys, overwriting they keys evrytime you find them, then your result is the array of Object.values` :

```js
const array1 = [
  { name: "name1", timestamp: "2018-09-15T07:00:00.0" },
  { name: "name2", timestamp: "2018-09-15T12:00:00.0" },
  { name: "name3", timestamp: "2018-09-28T05:00:00.0" },
  { name: "name4", timestamp: "2018-09-30T01:00:00.0" },
  { name: "name5", timestamp: "2018-10-02T10:00:00.0" },
  { name: "name6", timestamp: "2018-10-02T11:00:00.0" },
  { name: "name7", timestamp: "2018-10-15T07:00:00.0" },
  { name: "name8", timestamp: "2018-12-05T08:00:00.0" },
  { name: "name9", timestamp: "2018-12-05T09:00:00.0" },
  { name: "name10", timestamp: "2018-12-05T10:00:00.0" }
];

const result = array1.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const month = new Date(curr.timestamp).getMonth() + 1;
  acc[month] = curr;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(Object.values(result));
```

Comment: Thanks! It works good! Only thing I don't like is the newly created month object (mentioned in the comment in my first post) but for now I'm glad I have a working solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You could take the date part, and store each entry in a hastable under that date. Thus, every entry with the same month will override the previous one, and the last one will be kept:

```
 const byMonth = {};

 for(const { name, timestamp } of array1) {
   const month = timestamp.slice(0, 7);
   byMonth[month] = { name, timestamp };
 }

 const result = Object.values(byMonth);
```

```js
const array1 = [
  {name:"name1",timestamp:"2018-09-15T07:00:00.0"},
  {name:"name2",timestamp:"2018-09-15T12:00:00.0"},
  {name:"name3",timestamp:"2018-09-28T05:00:00.0"},
  {name:"name4",timestamp:"2018-09-30T01:00:00.0"},
  {name:"name5",timestamp:"2018-10-02T10:00:00.0"},
  {name:"name6",timestamp:"2018-10-02T11:00:00.0"},
  {name:"name7",timestamp:"2018-10-15T07:00:00.0"},
  {name:"name8",timestamp:"2018-12-05T08:00:00.0"},
  {name:"name9",timestamp:"2018-12-05T09:00:00.0"},
  {name:"name10",timestamp:"2018-12-05T10:00:00.0"}
];


 const byMonth = {};

 for(const { name, timestamp } of array1) {
   const month = timestamp.slice(0, 7);
   byMonth[month] = { name, timestamp };
 }

const result = Object.values(byMonth);

console.log(result);
```